# How do I pull a missing file back into my branch?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I have cloned a Git project into a local Git repository. Then I have done something nasty to one of the files and in that panic I deleted file physically from the drive (`rm style.css`) and also removed it from Git (`git rm style.css`).

I want to get the original `style.css` file back from origin to my development branch. Unfortunately my Git thinks it is up-to-date and won't do anything.

```
cd ~/project.me
git status

# On branch dev
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

git pull origin dev

Password for 'https://someone@github.com':
From https://github.com/somewhere/project.me
* branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

What do I need to do to tell git that I want to download original `style.css` file back into my dev branch?

Comment: if you want to restore but you are on a specific commit or branch check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803904/git-pull-doesnt-actually-restore-my-missing-files-from-remote

Comment: fyi sometimes the files are not fully updated for some mysterious reason. I found out that going to the root of the git project and running `git checkout <branch-name> .` fixed that issues.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use `git checkout`. In your case:

```
git checkout origin/master style.css
```

This command will update the requested file from the given branch (here the remote branch `origin/master`).

Comment: Thanks - this helped me too. If you have lots of files to restore (as I did) you can use: `git diff --name-status | sed -n '/^D/ s/^D\s*//gp' | xargs git checkout origin/master` which will re-checkout all the deleted files.

Comment: your answer is not general enough to help anyone. Perhaps make it more useful to everyone besides the OP?

Answer (score 86):

If you want to restore all the missing files from the local repository

```
git checkout .
```

**Warning**: This method also restores all changed files and drops all the changes

Comment: did not help in restoring missing files which are in the remote/master but not local

Comment: @vsync It can, but you have to run git fetch before

Comment: Restored local copies of remote files successfully. This is the easiest and best solution.

Answer (score 13):

Go to the location of file *style.css* (may be *app/css/*) using the console. Otherwise there will be *pathspec* error.

Then execute:

```
git checkout origin/master style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

I intentionally deleted some files from a clone `--depth 1`.

This brought the main files, and submodule ones, back:

```
git checkout . -f && git submodule update --checkout -f
```