# git pull doesn't actually restore my missing files from remote

Tags: git

I have been working on a branch.  I committed and pushed it up to the remote repository.  Now some files on that branch are missing.  Hopefully they are still available on the remote branch, so I tried to do `git pull`:

```
git pull origin feature/my_branch
```

However, git said all is synchronized with remote:

```
 * branch            feature/my_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

How can that be up to date? I cannot find my missing files locally, and my project didn't compile because of those missing files. Again, I can see those files in the commit history of the remote branch on bitbucket.

Comment: Are they still in the repository? Just because the files are still on the remote's file system, doesn't mean they exist in the repository. If you need to get the files back, just check out a commit that still had them, and then readd the files, and commit the new result.

Comment: Hi Alan, what you mean by checkout a commit ? `git log` show all commits on the branch, I reset to a commit I thought it contains the files but it doesn't ?

Comment: Can you elaborate in an answer? Thanx.

Comment: Were the files ever added to the repository in the first place?

Comment: git reset --hard && git pull

Comment: is there a way for git to discover by itself which files are not in sync with the branch? I keep running my python file and discover one by one which file is missing and then doing the pull. I also don't want to overwrite the ones I've edited myself.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`git pull` corresponds to the sequence of a `git fetch` and then `git merge`. So if you delete the files from your local repository, doing a `git pull` **will not** restore them.

In order to restore them you need to checkout that files from the remote repository using:

```
git checkout <branch name> -- <path/to/file>
```

`<branch name>` can be local or remote.

#### Example: Using remote repository

1. **Remote upstream name:** origin
2. **Remote branch:** feature/xpto
3. **Local branch:** feature/xpto
4. **File missing on local branch:** example.js
5. **Recover the file to the local branch from remote branch:** `git checkout    origin/feature/xpto -- example.js`
6. Now you have `example.js` back on your local branch

#### Example 2: Rollback a commit

1. `git log`
2. Current commit hash `7bb2154cf23b68feb0a0bbbd95446f2cd8bf3a44`
3. Want to rollback to this commit hash `dbc04c23b2c6f2dd7bc9b5ef4aef22611a57c3ad`

   - `git checkout dbc04c23b2c6f2dd7bc9b5ef4aef22611a57c3ad`
4. Only want to recover the file `example.js` from the above commit hash

   - `git checkout dbc04c23b2c6f2dd7bc9b5ef4aef22611a57c3ad -- example.js`

Comment: `git checkout <branch name>` will move to that branch, not restore it from remote.

Comment: `git checkout` works with remote or local branches and can grab specific files/paths or the whole branch. Is the same thing if you want to rollback a commit in your local repository you simple do: `git checkout <commit hash>` from your `git log`. See manual: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: what if I want to grab all the remote branch?

Comment: Malloc: if you want to grab the whole branch just do `git checkout <remote/branch_name>` without the **`--`** and the `path/file`

Comment: I am in the branch `feature/my_branch` and I want to grap it all from remote, I did `git checkout feature/my_branch` but git said `already on 'feature/my_branch'`, obviously. Are you sure of that? have you tried and does it grab the remote branch on your case?

Comment: `git checkout origin/feature/my_branch` make a new branch with the most recent commit hash. Ok, but the missing files which I can see on remote aren't backed in local.

Comment: I guess you didn't saw the whole command, you probably missed the `-- path/to/file`part of the command. Example: `git checkout remote/feature/branch -- example.js` This will get the example.js file from the root directory of the remote branch.

Comment: Hi, Thanx for your reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't seems to work either. Weird issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the files are on the remote branch that you are checking out? or have you seen the log of your local branch to see where did you deleted them?

Comment: Try a simple test, checkout your remote branch to a new local branch: `git checkout remote/branch -b local_branch` and now see if you have the files on your local system.

Comment: What does this `--` do? What if I write: `git checkout #SomeHash FileName` without `--`, what will happen?

Comment: is there a way for git to discover by itself which files are not in sync with the branch? I keep running my python file and discover one by one which file is missing and then doing the pull. I also don't want to overwrite the ones I've edited myself.

Comment: fyi sometimes the files are not fully updated for some mysterious reason. I found out that going to the root of the git project and running `git checkout <branch-name> .` fixed that issues.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you've described the problem correctly, @danielcsgomes's methods should work fine.

You can find out which files are in your current commit, but not in your working directory, by running `git status`.  For instance (using `-s` to keep the output short):

```
$ rm structy.py
$ git status -s
 D structy.py
```

To get just that one file back:

```
$ git checkout -- structy.py
```

and it's back.

Sometimes simply checking out some other branch or revision, then going back to where you were, will do the trick.  For instance, the most recent commit on `master` here was to add `mp.py`, so if I do this:

```
$ rm mp.py
$ git status -s
 D mp.py
$ git checkout HEAD^
Note: checking out 'HEAD^'.
[verbiage about detached HEAD etc, snipped]
$ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was 171ce6f... ignore *.log files
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git status -s
$ head -1 mp.py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
```

But this does not always work.  It works for `mp.py` because the previous rev (`HEAD^`) doesn't have it, and the current one (`master`) does, so moving forward from `HEAD^` to `master` restores the file.  The file `structy.py` has been around for quite a while though, so if I remove it and check out `HEAD^` or some other branch or whatever, it remains deleted-from-work-dir.  So something like `git checkout -- structy.py` is an easier way to restore it, unless you want to go for the Very Big Hammer: `git reset --hard`.

If you're sure you want to abandon any changes you've made, you can `git reset --hard HEAD`.  For instance, consider:

```
$ git rm mp.py
rm 'mp.py'
$ git status -s
D  mp.py
```

(by the way, note that the "D" is in a different position here: I "git rm"ed, not just "rm"ed, so I'm telling git that if I do a commit, mp.py should be removed in the new commit, it's not just an accident that I removed it).  Then I decide, no, this is wrong, I want everything back to the way it was in HEAD:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at 523bacb add multiprocessing example
$ git status -s
$
```

So, only use `reset --hard` if you're quite sure.

Comment: is there a way for git to discover by itself which files are not in sync with the branch? I keep running my python file and discover one by one which file is missing and then doing the pull. I also don't want to overwrite the ones I've edited myself.

Comment: fyi sometimes the files are not fully updated for some mysterious reason. I found out that going to the root of the git project and running `git checkout <branch-name> .` fixed that issues.

Comment: @CharlieParker: Except while you're doing work in a repository (which is a pretty big "except"), Git is never about *files*, it's about *commits*. It's a good idea to break `git pull` apart into its two separate components: `git fetch`, plus a second Git command of your choice. The `git fetch` operation is *only* about *commits*. The second operation is *mostly* about commits but can affect or require the use of your *working tree*, which is the place you find individual files.

Comment: When it comes to individual files—i.e., when you're actually doing work, inside the working tree of a Git repository—that's when commands like `git status`, `git restore`, `git checkout <commit> -- <path>`, etc., start to come into play. I advise people (for their own sanity) to keep this part as separate as possible from the other parts of Git where you work with whole commits at a time (`git fetch`, `git merge`, etc).

Comment: @CharlieParker: so, for this case, use `git status`: you're in the working tree and you're working with the files in that working tree. The `git status` command will run two `git diff` commands for you, one to compare the *current commit* (in `HEAD`) vs Git's index / staging-area, and then a second `git diff` to compare the index/staging-area to your current working tree files. If the *first* diff is empty (so that you have nothing "staged for commit"), the *second* diff tells you exactly what you wanted to know here.