# xcodeproj file has disappeared?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

All the `.h` and `.m` files are in the folder for a particular app I'm working on, but the `xcodeproj` file is missing, even though I worked on it less than a week ago. Looking in the Finder doesn't bring it up (though it brings up lots of OTHER xcodeproj files).

I've looked for answers to this question but I'm not understanding what I've found so I can't tell whether it helps.

I'm sure it's something completely obvious, especially as I'm very new to source control and git. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you are looking in the wrong folder for the xcodeproj, or that it is not currently on your system and you have to retrieve it from the repository.

Perhaps you are viewing a folder that's one level down from where the xcodeproj file is. Move up the filesystem hierarchy and see if you find the file. If you're not concerned where the file is on your system and you just want to open it in Xcode, use Xcode's **File > Open Recent** menu item.

If those attempts fail, you may have to check out the missing file:

[How do I pull a missing file back into my branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705626/how-do-i-pull-missing-file-back-into-my-branch)

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have to retrieve it from the repository--though this seems strange as I swear to Gosh it was on my system.